# Overloading operator to merge vectors

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, std

I want to overload the operator + in a class which has a vector as member variable, so as to carry out the merging of vectors of two different objects. In other words I would like a new object to be created which has as vector both the elements of the vectors of the two initial vectors in a row. I try the following code and I receive an error in operator+ regarding std::copy. What is the problem?

```
class TestVector
{
    std::vector<int> myVector;

public:
    TestVector(){};
    TestVector(std::vector<int>);
    std::vector<int> getVector();
    TestVector operator +(TestVector);

};

std::vector<int> TestVector::getVector()
{
   return myVector;
}

TestVector TestVector::operator+(TestVector param)
{

    std::vector<int> tempVector;
    std::vector<int> paramVector = param.getVector();

    std::copy(paramVector.begin(), paramVector.end(), tempVector);
    std::copy(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), tempVector.end());

    TestVector TestVector1(tempVector);

    return TestVector1;

}
```

Moreover, is the second copy statement valid to merge two vectors in general?

**Update:** I got an error at execution time saying that iterators are inompatible at this statement. What is wrong?
    tempVector.insert(tempVector.end(),param.getVector().begin(), param.getVector().end());

Comment: It's useful to include the *actual* text of the error message.

Comment: You might also consider the `insert` member function: `target.insert(target.end(), source.begin(), source.end());`

Comment: Re:update. I added one more statement: std::vector<int> paramVector = param.getVector() above the error prone line and the problem eliminated. I inserted then paramVector.begin(), paramVector.end() as iterators.

Comment: Re: update, with your current version of `getVector()` you can't specify a range with `a.getVector().begin()` and `a.getVector().end()` as `getVector` returns a copy of the internally held vector. This would only  work if `getVector()` returned a reference to the same object for each call, otherwise you have to store the copy returned by `getVector()` and use `.begin()` and `.end()` on this copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument to `std::copy` must be an iterator, not a container. You can use `std::back_inserter` thus:

```
std::copy(paramVector.begin(), paramVector.end(), std::back_inserter(tempVector));
```

The second copy will compile, since `std::end()` returns an iterator, but it will break because the iterator simply points to the end of the vector. It won't grow the vector when `std::copy` tries to assign to it; it will simply invoke undefined behaviour. Again, `std::back_inserter` solves the problem.

In any event you don't need `std::copy` at all, since `std::vector` provides the necessary semantics directly:

```
TestVector TestVector::operator+(const TestVector& v)
{
    std::vector<int> t(myVector);
    t.insert(t.end(), v.myVector.begin(), v.myVector.end());
    return TestVector(t);
}
```

And remember to use `const &…` to avoid so much copying. For instance, the second constructor copies the input vector unnecessarily, and `getVector()` copies the internal vector unnecessarily.

Even the above solution copies the temporary vector at least once, which can be avoided with a purpose-built constructor:

```
class TestVector
{
    std::vector<int> myVector;

public:
    TestVector() { }
    TestVector(const std::vector<int>& v) : myVector(v) { }
    const std::vector<int>& getVector() const { return myVector; }
    TestVector operator+(const TestVector& v) const {
        return TestVector(op_add(), *this, v);
    }

private:
    struct op_add { };
    TestVector(op_add, const TestVector& a, const TestVector& b) : myVector(a) {
        myVector.insert(myVector.end(), b.myVector.begin(), b.myVector.end());
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, finally it works also with tempVector.begin(), my omission

Comment: Yes. I realized that I did superflous things, just distressed by not being able to detect the error.

Comment: I need the second constructor to initialize an object with a vector.  I think getVector() is essential as well, as myVector is private. Isn' t it?

Comment: @arjacsoh: My point was not that they shouldn't be there (I've added them to the final version of my answer.) but that they should use const-references instead of copying.

Answer (score 1):

The third paramter to `std::copy` should be some sort of output iterator. The safest thing to use would be an insert iterator. After a `#include <iterator>` you should be able to do something like:

```
std::copy(paramVector.begin(), paramVector.end(), std::back_inserter(tempVector));
std::copy(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), std::back_inserter(tempVector));
```

`std::back_inserter` is a helper function template that creates the appropriate `back_insert_iterator` for the given container.

Also note that you are making quite a lot of copies. Personally, I would make `operator+` a free function and take the parameters by const reference. At the moment your `operator+` is non-const, so can only be called on non-const vectors and takes its second parameter by copy. If `getVector` were declared: `const TestVector& getVector() const;` then you could do something like this.

```
TestVector operator+(const TestVector& lhs, const TestVector& rhs)
{
    std::vector<int> ret( lhs.getVector() );
    ret.insert( ret.end(), rhs.getVector().begin(), rhs.getVector().end() );
    return TempVector(ret);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to implement `operator+` for your type, I would recommend that you also implement `operator+=` as a member function and then `operator+` in terms of the previous operator:

```
// As a public member function
TestVector& TestVector::operator+=( const TestVector& rhs ) {
   myVector.insert( myVector.end(), rhs.myVector.begin(), rhs.myVector.end();
   return *this;
}

TestVector operator+( TestVector lhs, const TestVector& rhs ) {
   lhs += rhs;
   return lhs;
}
```

The advantage is that you only need a couple more lines of code and you get a new operation for free, it does not require friendship or providing accessors to the internal details of the type and is efficient (does not require copying) for the case where the user code does not need to maintain the left hand side operator. At the same time, the implementation of `operator+` can be done as a free function (symmetry with respect to types --i.e. conversions <sup>1</sup>) and efficient (in a C++11 compiler it will copy each element only once if `TestVector` has a move constructor which it should since the only member is a vector that is movable; in C++03 there is an extra copy in the return statement that can be removed by deafult constructing and swapping).

<sup>1</sup> Note: you might want to consider making the `TestVector( std::vector<int> const & )` explicit to avoid implicit conversions to `TestVector`.